# Derivation of Fourier Series of a Real Signal

Tags: fourier-series

I was asked to do the following thing.

Consider the fourier series of a signal given by

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_ke^{jk\omega_0t}$$

Let's consider an approaches to this series given by the truncated series.

$$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} a_ke^{jk\omega_0t}$$

a- Show that if $x(t)$ is real then the series can be rewritten as

$$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} A_k\cos(k\omega_0t +\phi_k)$$

b- How can we calculate $A_k$ and $\phi_k$ knowing $a_k$?

Here goes my attempt:

So I first thought of putting together the k term and the (-k term). I have a doubt about how to get the expression of the series by doing this but I will clear it up after my proof.

We will have then:

$$a_ke^{jk\omega_0t} + a_{-k}e^{-jk\omega_0t}$$

Because x is real then $a_{-k}=a_k*$ where $a_k*$ is the conjugate of $a_k$.

We will have then

$$a_ke^{jk\omega_0t} + a_k*e^{-jk\omega_0t}$$
$$a_ke^{jk\omega_0t} + (a_k e^{jk\omega_0t})*$$
$$2 \operatorname{Re} (a_ke^{jk\omega_0t})$$

If we make $a_k = A_k e^{\phi_k}$ we will have:

$$2 \operatorname{Re} (A_ke^{j(k\omega_0t + \phi_k)})$$
$$2 A_k \cos(k\omega_0t + \phi_k)$$

Now my main doubt here is that factor of 2 and how it will affect the way I will express my calculations.

My first thought was: I reached this expression because I summed up two terms of the series. That means one term will be half what I calculates. Therefore, the series will be:

$$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} A_k\cos(k\omega_0t +\phi_k)$$

Therefore, to answer question b I will just have to remember that $$a_k = A_k e^{\phi_k}$$ and so I will get to:

$$A_k = |a_k|$$
$$\phi_k = \arg(a_k)$$

But I'm not sure if this last few steps are correct, if my elimination of the 2 factor is correct. Or should I do:

$$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} 2 A_k\cos(k\omega_0t +\phi_k)$$ 
$$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N} A'_k\cos(k\omega_0t +\phi_k)$$

and then 
$$A'_k = |a_k|/2$$
$$\phi_k = \arg(a_k)$$

Can someone clarify this to me please? Which process is correct and why? Thanks!